# Laravel on AWS with SSL - 404 Not Found errors

Tags: laravel, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a laravel project I am trying to run on AWS Elasticbeanstalk - I uploaded the project and worked 100% using HTTP, the client decided they wanted SSL , when I upload the exact same source code, my landing page works perfectly (https://sitename/), however any other page such as https://sitename/login will not work at all and I receive a 404 Not Found errors message.

The output I have is as follows (I zero'ed out the ip address except the last section to give it context):

```
2022/05/25 03:51:46 [error] 7872#7872: *21072 open() "/var/www/html/public/login" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 000.00.00.164, server: , request: "GET /login HTTP/1.1", host: "00.000.000.113"
2022/05/25 03:57:03 [error] 7871#7871: *21210 open() "/var/www/html/public/_debugbar/assets/javascript" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 000.00.00.164, server: , request: "GET /_debugbar/assets/javascript?v=1644364352 HTTP/1.1", host: "portal.sitename", referrer: "https://portal.sitename/"
2022/05/25 03:57:03 [error] 7872#7872: *21209 open() "/var/www/html/public/_debugbar/assets/stylesheets" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 000.00.00.164, server: , request: "GET /_debugbar/assets/stylesheets?v=1644364352&theme=auto HTTP/1.1", host: "portal.sitename", referrer: "https://portal.sitename/"
2022/05/25 04:01:26 [error] 7872#7872: *21313 open() "/var/www/html/public/ReportServer" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 000.00.00.193, server: , request: "GET /ReportServer HTTP/1.1", host: "13.244.47.136"
2022/05/25 04:01:39 [error] 7872#7872: *21320 open() "/var/www/html/public/ReportServer" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 000.00.00.164, server: , request: "GET /ReportServer HTTP/1.1", host: "00.000.000.113"
2022/05/25 04:08:15 [error] 7872#7872: *21477 open() "/var/www/html/public/login" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 000.00.00.193, server: , request: "POST /login HTTP/1.1", host: "portal.sitename", referrer: "https://portal.sitename/"
```

Comment: Are you using nginx or apace in Elastic Benstalk?

Comment: How did you setup SSL Cert?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to all for assisting , for anyone following this is what I did to resolve:

```
cd  /etc/nginx/conf.d/elasticbeanstalk
nano laravel.conf
```

added the following code:

```
location / { 
try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because your server is not accepting query string in url. For solving this you should add another folder called **.platform** and follow the text inside **laravel.conf** file like below. This will be fixed
Be sure you are using nginx as server from elastic benstalk configuration

[.platform configuration](https://prnt.sc/WHs6p-_lS2zC)

laravel.conf file

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    gzip_static on;
}
```

Comment: I assume you mean create .platform  and the directory structure from the /var/www/html

Comment: you should create your .ebextensions directory along with public, config, database, storage directory . and just push to elastic benstalk using aws codepipeline and deploy. Then rest will be done by aws elastic benstalk

Comment: I recently deployed two laravel app using elb, ec2, pipeline, codedeploy,pipeline, codebuild, s3 easily in amazon cloud .

Answer (score 0):

There's [documentation available](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/php-laravel-tutorial.html) for laravel in combination with beanstalk.

Your issue is caused by the webserver searching for files in the wrong directory. Did you choose PHP as platform? And do you have set the Document Root to /public?

Comment: I certainly did change it to /public, other wise it wouldnt see my landing page at all

Comment: I used that exact documentation as per my original post, it worked 100% using HTTP, as soon as a cert was installed and I point to https , the problems started